# Shopify / Liquid - inserting product recommendations onto cart page

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I want to add product recommendations on my shopify cart page.

I have added:
`{% section 'product-recommendations' %}`  in the `cart.liquid` file.

This file consists of:

```
{%- if section.settings.show_product_recommendations -%}
  {%- if recommendations.performed -%}
{%- if recommendations.products_count > 0 -%}
      <div class="product-recommendations__inner">
        {%- if section.settings.heading != blank -%}
        
          <div class="section-header">
            <h2>{{ section.settings.heading | escape }}</h2>
          </div>
        {%- endif -%}
        <ul data-slides="8" id='product-slider' class="grid grid--uniform grid--view-items product-slider">
          {%- for product in recommendations.products -%}
            <li class="grid__item small--one-half medium-up--one-quarter">
              {% include 'product-card-grid', max_height: 250, product: product, show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor %}
            </li>
          {%- endfor -%}
        </ul>
      </div>
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- else  -%}
    <div class="page-width recommendations-container" data-base-url="{{ routes.product_recommendations_url }}" data-product-id="{{ product.id }}" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="product-recommendations"></div>
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endif -%}
```

It is being inserted into the page (I can see the container), but nothing actually renders other than the container margin/padding. I suspect its because I'm not on a product page.

How would I make this work on the cart page?

Comment: At least share the code of *product-recommendations.liquid* so we can see the code that is not displaying anything.

Comment: @BilalAkbar I have shared this - it should be standard Shopify debut theme code. I have not gone on to provide the code for the 'product-card-grid' which is included - this should also be the standard code - I wouldn't have thought that affects it but can provide if needed. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it did not work was same that you concluded, that it was not a product page. However, given the product ID we can get the recommendations of any product. The [Shopify Docs for Recommendations object](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/recommendations) state

> The recommendations object returns products only if it's used in a
> theme section that's rendered through an **HTTP** request to
> **<base_url>?section_id=<section_id>&product_id=<product_id>**. **section_id**
> is the ID of the section where the recommendations object is being
> used, and **product_id** is the ID of the product you want to show
> recommended products for. To determine the **base_url**, use the
> **routes.product_recommendations_url** attribute. Using the routes object
> rather than a hardcoded URL ensures that the product recommendations
> load in the correct locale.

So, unlike Shopify product page, where product object is globally available, you have to pass product ID from Shopify cart items. To do so, add a new section named **product-recommendations-cart** and include it in your cart template.

```
{% comment %}
  The contents of the cart.liquid template can be found in /sections/cart-template.liquid
{% endcomment %}

{% section 'cart-template' %}
{% section 'product-recommendations-cart' %}
```

Then inside product-recommendations-cart section

```
{%- if section.settings.show_product_recommendations and cart.item_count > 0 -%}

{%- for item in cart.items -%}
    {%- assign product_rec = item.product -%}
{%- endfor -%}

  {%- if recommendations.performed -%}
    {%- if recommendations.products_count > 0 -%}
      <div class="product-recommendations__inner">
        {%- if section.settings.heading != blank -%}
          <div class="section-header text-center">
            <h2>{{ section.settings.heading | escape }}</h2>
          </div>
        {%- endif -%}
        <ul class="grid grid--uniform grid--view-items">
          {%- for product in recommendations.products -%}
          
           {%- assign display = true -%}
            
            {%- for item in cart.items -%}
                {%- if item.product.id == product.id -%}
                    {%- assign display = false -%}
                {%- endif -%}
            {%- endfor -%}
          
          {%- if display == true -%}
            <li class="grid__item small--one-half medium-up--one-quarter">
              {% include 'product-card-grid', max_height: 250, product: product, show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor %}
            </li>
          {%- endif -%}
          
          {%- endfor -%}
        </ul>
      </div>
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- else  -%}
    <div class="page-width" data-base-url="{{ routes.product_recommendations_url }}" data-product-id="{{ product_rec.id }}" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="product-recommendations"></div>
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endif -%}
{% schema %}
{
  "name": {
    "en": "Product Recommend Cart"
  },
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_product_recommendations",
      "label": {
        "en": "Show dynamic recommendations"
      },
      "info": {      
        "en": "Dynamic recommendations change and improve with time. [Learn more](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/recommended-products)"
      },
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "heading",
      "label": {
        "en": "Heading"
      },
      "default": {
        "en": "You may also like"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_vendor",
      "label": {
        "en": "Show vendor"
      },
      "default": false
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Here, I added the condtion to display only if cart has some items and used the last product in cart to get recommendations.

As per your comment, I have added the condition to skip products that are already in cart. You can improve this using a string of product ids in cart instead of looping all cart items again and again.

If you need more control, use [Product recommendations with the Product Recommendations API products response.](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/develop-theme-recommended-products-using-json-api)

Comment: How would you go about only recommending products that are not held in the cart? As I do notice that it recommends other items already in the cart

Comment: Any idea if it is possible to supply multiple source products, so you can reference ALL items in cart?

Comment: @iamkeir I don't think so. As this was designed to be used on single product pages. However, a workaround can be to include multiple sections with different product Ids and then pick and choose based on your conditions.

Comment: @BilalAkbar that's a good shout - and yes I think you're right, single product only as source product. Anyway, thanks for your posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.getJSON("/recommendations/products.json?product_id=" + item.product_id + "&limit=6&section_id=custom-cart", function(response) {
  var recommendedProducts = response.products;
  $.each(recommendedProducts, function(index,recommended){
    console.log(recommended)
  });
});
```

You can also create a cart recommendations using jQuery.

Here I added the jQuery code. In this ajax call response you will get the recommendations product JSON.

Instead of item.product_id you can use your cart item id and instead of custom-cart you can add you section name where you html is created.